# Short story about a drug that suspends the user's conscious experience of events

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is about a drug that suspends the user's conscious experience of the world, with no other intended effect. They're still the same person, doing all the things they normally would, except they don't consciously experience anything until the effect has worn off.

The plot may have explored a rare, catastrophic side effect, wherein a user's personality was radically different after using the drug.

I also remember that the phrase "The king is dead, long live the king" (or queen?) was used as a metaphor to explain how the drug interacted with a person's consciousness.

I think it was published in one of the (many) editions of Gardner Dozois' *The Year's Best Science Fiction*, although I don't want to speculate which one because I really have no idea.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is *[Second Person, Present Tense](https://clarkesworldmagazine.com/gregory_11_17_reprint/)* by Daryl Gregory. It was published in [*The Year’s Best Science Fiction #23*](https://www.sfsignal.com/archives/2006/08/review_the_years_best_science_fiction_23_edited_by_gardner_dozois/) edited by Gardner Dozois.

> The designer drug, called Zombie or Zen, increases the time between
> action and thought, with thought coming much later, similar to
> conscious blackouts. An overdose essentially purges the victim’s
> identity. They have memory of their previous lives, but they don’t
> have the feeling of experience. Therese, who now wants to be called
> Terry, struggles with the person she is being made to become. The
> situation offers some thought-provoking moments about identity and
> human rights. Terry is a sympathetic character, as are her struggling
> parents. Amidst all this contemplation, the story also holds a
> surprise or two.

You can read it in full [here](https://clarkesworldmagazine.com/gregory_11_17_reprint/);

> *The Queen is dead. Long live the Queen.*

Comment: This is definitely it. Thank you!